# Hide all <table> when load a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have total 15 table on my web page. I need to hide all of this  when loading this page.
I am trying to do this like: 
but it's not working. anyone can help me, please?

```
 window.onload = function() {
        var tableEL = $("table");
         for (var i = 0; i < tableEL.length; i++) {
        tableEL[i].hide();

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("table").hide();
};
```

It will hide all table presented on the page.

Comment: $("table")hide(); or $("table").hide(); 
may be you mistake a dot(.). 
bt when i try this? when my JS is load?

Comment: @brk just a mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$` while selecting the `table` inside the loop.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var tableEL = $("table");
  for (var i = 0; i < tableEL.length; i++) {
    $(tableEL[i]).hide();

  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use CSS to `hide` the tables

```
table{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

```
$(function(){
     $("table").hide(); // this will execute after loading the page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>4</td></tr></table>
```

`$('table').hide();` in jQuery will have this effect.  Make sure you do it after the document is fully loaded or the tables will not be loaded into the DOM and then jQuery will try to hide the tables before they exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).load(function(){
  $('table').hide();

});
```